# How to calculate the factor $ k_{i}$

Tags: probability

I'm need to decide how large should be a recipient to be used to grow fungus.

Each day, a random event generates one of $z$ outcomes.

The probability of each outcome is $p_i; \; 1\leq i \leq z$, and it generates an weight $a_i$ of fungus.

[EDIT] $\sum _{i=1} ^z p_i =1$ and $0 \leq  p_i \leq 1$

But each day, the fungus $a_i$ grows by a fraction c.

After a very large number of $n$ days, I assume that the total weight of fungus is $W=\sum _{i=1} ^z (p_i . n).\left (  a_i.(1+c)^{k_{i}}\right )$

I cannot figure how to calculate the factor $k_i$, because, if an event has a large probability, then it would be more probably present at the start, and grow exponentially more than the rest, so $k_i$ must be function of the probability $p_i$

I tried to use the formula for the future value of an annuity: $FV =a. \frac{(1+c)^n-1}{c}$. But that formula is valid only if every $a_i$ is the same for each roll dice.

I don't even know how to check the validity of the formula, other than running a simulation with a large number of roll dices.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: I do not see why the probability would not be a number between zero and one. It is by definition.

Comment: I think I misread it. Sorry about that.